# Reversing order of recursive output

Tags: java, recursion, queue

I'm making a singly-linked queue for a CS assignment and one I was supposed to implement a toString method that displays the elements as such: IN -> [ “data 1” , “data 2” , “data 3” ] -> OUT.

However, my first node is the one thats been there for the latest, my method returns the oldest element next to IN and the newest by OUT, which I think is the reverse order.

Here's my code:

```
public String toString() {
        if(value == null){
            return "";
        }
        else if(next == null){
            return "\"" + value + "\"";
        }
        else {
            return "\"" + value + "\" ; " + next.toString();
        }    
}
```

Is there a way that I can easily reverse this order?

Thanks

Comment: Reverse the order you print `return next.toString() + "\"" + value + "\" ;";`